# How to prove absence of a total order relation?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that on $\mathbb{C}$ (complex) there is no total order relation $≤$ such that both if the following properties hold

1. $∀ (x, y, z) ∈ \mathbb{C}^3$, $x ≤ y \implies x + z ≤ y + z$ and
2. $z ≥ 0, x ≤ y \implies xz ≤ yz$

I know that I want to prove that it is only a partial order relation. However, it is known that $x ≤ y$ exists. However, because $≤$ is partial, it may be that neither $x ≤ y$ or $y ≤ x$.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Hint: We either have $i>0$ or $0>i$. Show that both lead to contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

The properties dictate that $ 0 \leq -1 $ is false because otherwise

$$ x \leq y \implies_{(+ -y)} x - y \leq 0 \implies_{(* -1)} y - x \leq 0 \implies_{(+x)} y \leq x \implies x = y $$ Which contradicts the fact that there is more then a single complex number.

Assume that there is a total order.

Since it is a total order either  $ 0 \leq i $ or $ 0 \leq -i $

In the $ 0 \leq i $ case we can multiply both sides by i. $ 0 \leq -1 $ which is false.

In the $ 0 \leq -i $ case we can multiply both sides by -i. $ 0 \leq -1 $ which is false.

Since all cases lead to conditions we can conclude that a total order is imposable.

Comment: We don't know in advance that $\leq$ on the reals is the usual order, so $\neg (0\leq -1)$$ needs to be justified.

Comment: I added an argument justifying it.

Comment: I found your notation for it puzzling at first but I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

By (2), $$0\leq i\implies 0=0.i\leq i.i\implies 0=(0.i).i\leq (i.i).i=-i.$$ But then ,by (1), $$0\leq i\implies 0\leq -i\implies i=(0)+i\leq (-i)+i=0,$$ giving $i\leq 0 \leq i,$ which implies $i=0$ because $\leq$ is a total order. Changing $\leq$ to $\geq,$ word for word, gives $0\geq i\implies i\geq 0\geq i,$ again implying $i=0.$